# Selection is completely borked in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

Let's say I want to select some text in the app:

[image]

So far it's all good, but when I try refining my selection with the little knobs<sup>1</sup>,

- when moving them left or right, instead of the selection changing, the entire questions/answers panel is slid
- when moving up or down, it scrolls

Could this be unborkified? I'm using a Galaxy S4 on Android 4.3.

<sup>1: I've been wanting to use this word in a question for a while! Now I need to find a way to use "door"</sup>

Comment: Isn't that a function of the phone OS, and not the app?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Perhaps, but not being able to select text on an extremely commonly used phone (Galaxy S4, editing it in) sounds like a problem to me.

Comment: I think it is more of a needing to be careful of how you (you as a general you, not you specifically) are pulling the handles, I can reproduce this on a Nexus 7 tablet. But it also happens nearly anything I try select text on Android.

Comment: @Howlin Really? This seems to be the only app for which I have this problem. In any case, no matter how hard or slowly I try, the question/answer pane refuses to stay still.

Comment: The horizontal movement is moot after the renewal of Q&A page on a single thread. However, for vertical movement, is it still happening? For some reason, I couldn't repro this on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app 1.0.82 (beta), the screen was scroll-locked while moving the knobs.